# Spark - Manipulate specific column value in a dataframe (remove chars)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark-csv to read a file and convert it into data frame.
Specific column, X let's call it, have a range of values - 0 to 2,
but some of the rows has an annoying trailing `;N` which I need to remove.

e.g.

```
 _________
| ID | X  |
|---------|
| 1  | 0;N|
```

How can I do this with Spark?
It's all new to me.
I'm guessing it involves some use of "filter" but I couldn't resolve it.

DataFrame is loaded as follows, if that's an important info:

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, GroupedData
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sys.path.append("$SPARK_HOME/python/lib")

# Init steps
sc = SparkContext('local')
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

print "Loading file... ",
log_df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').\
options(header='true', inferschema='true', delimiter='\t').\
load('/path/to/file.csv')  # Load data file
print "Done!"

log_df.select('X').show(20, False)
```

Last line is where I see a table that some rows do have 0-2 values, 
while other have trailing `;N` that I want to remove

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, col
log_df.withColumn("X",regexp_replace(col("X"), ";N", "")).show()
```

Comment: i ended up using lambda function with udf in the following manner:

`udf = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: x[:1] if len(x) > 1 else x, StringType())

df = df.withColumn('X', udf(df['X']).cast(IntegerType()))`

I'm also accepting your answer, thank you